# How to get color of a particular stack on click of a stacked bar chart in kendo UI using angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, kendo-ui

I want to retrieve the color of clicked portion of stack in stacked bar chart using angularjs in kendoUI.

Comment: thanks @ezanker :) I have placed this bar chart inside an iframe in angularjs. I want to retieve that color value from iframe. How I will get that value from iframe

Comment: I am new to this... can anyone help me???plzzz...

Comment: Here am getting the color of clicked portion and value of x-axis ie time(in my case).but am passing this time to webservice and my time is in utc format.but I displayed in my graph time as only hour and minutes.I have to pass the utc format time to webservice while clicking the stack.how is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[seriesClick](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#events-seriesClick)** event:

```
seriesClick: function(e) {
    alert(e.series.color);
}
```

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/OQOCU)**

Here is a demo using Angular:

## **[Angular DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/IcUMU)**